# Finding and b in an equation with a floor function

Tags: number-theory

\begin{align}
    a^2 + ba + c &= 0 & \text{{No real roots.}}\\
    \lfloor a^2 \rfloor + ba + c &= 0 & \text{{At least one real roots.}}
\end{align}

Are there any values of b and c that will make the given number of roots correct?

The first thing I thought about doing was finding the discriminant .In order for the first equation to have no real roots, we must have $b^2 – 4c < 0$. That means that $b^2 < 4c$. 
I know that the discriminant of the second one must be 0 but I am not sure how to express it because a floor function is involved. What should I do? 
Will this approach get me anywhere or are there any better methods?

Comment: Hi Richard! Welcome to Maths SE. That is an interesting question! Definitely the discriminant will be helpful in knowing if there is a solution at all, especially in the first case. In the second case, you cannot really calculate the discriminant, but perhaps you can learn something by doing some sketching?

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
    x^2 + bx + c &= 0 & \text{{No real roots.}}\\
    \lfloor x^2 \rfloor + bx + c &= 0 & \text{{At least one real root.}}
\end{align}

Let's start by noting that the discriminant of $x^2 + bx + c$ is
$b^2 - 4c$. Hence  $x^2 + bx + c$ has no real roots if and only if $b^2 - 4c < 0$, which is true if and only if $c - \dfrac{b^2}{4} > 0$.  For convenience, let's define $$\Delta = c - \dfrac{b^2}{4}$$
and from here on, it will turn out to be necessary to assume that $0 < \Delta < 1$.

Let $f(x) = \lfloor x^2 \rfloor + bx + c$

If $x$ is an integer, then $f(x) = x^2 + bx + c$ which we assume has no real roots. So the roots of $f(x)$ cannot be an integer.

Since $x^2 - 1 < \lfloor x^2 \rfloor \le x^2$, then

$x^2 + bx + (c-1) < f(x) < x^2 + bx + c$

So, if $f(x) = 0$,
\begin{array}{c}
    x^2 + bx + (c-1) < 0 < x^2 + bx + c \\
    -x^2 - bx - c < 0 < -x^2 - bx + (1-c) \\
    0 < x^2 + bx + c < 1 \\
    0 < \left(x + \dfrac b2 \right)^2 + \Delta < 1 \\
    0 \le \left(x + \dfrac b2 \right)^2 < 1 - \Delta \\
    \left|x + \dfrac b2 \right| \lt \sqrt{1 - \Delta}
\end{array}

So all possible solutions to $f(x) = 0$ are in the interval
$\left( -\dfrac b2 - \sqrt{1 - \Delta}, -\dfrac b2 + \sqrt{1 - \Delta} \right)$.

This range can be partitioned into intervals of the form $(-\sqrt{n+1}, -\sqrt n]$ or $[\sqrt n, \sqrt{n+1})$ and each interval will contain $0$ or $1$ solutions as follows.

If $-\dfrac{n+c}{b}\in (\sqrt{n+1}, \sqrt n]$ then it is a root of $f(x)$.

If $-\dfrac{n+c}{b}\in [-\sqrt n, -\sqrt{n-1})$ then it is a root of $f(x)$.

### Example

Let $f(x) = \lfloor x^2 \rfloor + 3x + 3$

Then $0 < \Delta = \dfrac 34 < 1$ and $\sqrt{1 - \Delta} = \dfrac 12$

So all possible solutions to $f(x) = 0$ are in the interval
$\left( -\dfrac 32 - \dfrac 12, -\dfrac 32 + \dfrac 12 \right) = ( -2, -1)$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{n} & \text{interval} & a=-\dfrac{n+c}{b} & \lfloor a^2 \rfloor + ba + c \\
\hline
4 & (-\sqrt 5, -\sqrt 4] & -\dfrac 73 & \text{not in interval} \\
3 & (-\sqrt 4, -\sqrt 3] &         -2 & \text{not in interval} \\
2 & (-\sqrt 3, -\sqrt 2] & -\dfrac 53 &          2 - 5 + 3 = 0 \\
1 & (-\sqrt 2, -\sqrt 1] & -\dfrac 43 &          1 - 4 + 3 = 0 \\
0 & (-\sqrt 1, -\sqrt 0] &         -1 & \text{not in interval} \\
\hline
\end{array}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok with finding the discriminant.
Now plot $$
\eqalign{
  & y =  - bx - c  \cr 
  & y = x^{\,2}   \cr 
  & y = \left\lfloor {x^{\,2} } \right\rfloor  \cr} 
$$
and that will show you how to proceed.